# Hill Cipher Encryption / Decryption Source Code Java (2 x 2 matrix key)

Tags: java, algorithm, encryption, sample

I have a project to make an encryption and decryption for string input in java. I've been stucked for a week doing some research in it. I really appreciate if you have sample **source code or function method** for **Hill cipher in java** that I may use in my project. 
I really need your help ... hope someone out there could be my savior. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://pjcodingcenter.blogspot.in/2013/03/implementing-hill-cipher-substitution.html

Another simplistic one :
[Hill Cipher](http://javaraiders.blogspot.in/2012/11/hill-cipher.html)

Google got me this!! See if it works..

Answer (score 0):

For encryption take a look at [this git repo](http://github.com/jester155/HillCipher). The project at the link provided does handle 2x2 decryption.